# AWS Lambda authority error while using dynamoDB at lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using AWS Lambda as root account. but when I try to add dynamo-db as trigger in lambda, AWS said some authority errors occurred.

```
Please ensure the role can perform the GetRecords, GetShardIterator, DescribeStream, ListShards, and ListStreams Actions on your stream in IAM.
```

I'm using root account, why authority error occurred?
I want to use root account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i'm using root account, why authority error occurred? i want to use root account

Your functions, uses [lambda execute role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html), your IAM user/root permissions do not apply here. You have to updated the execution role with DyndamoDB permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions used execution role to access AWS services and resources, this can be set in the lambda creation wizard or in the cloud formation script

Step 1.
Role: !GetAtt DeleteAppConfigurationsLambdaRole.Arn . Details [here][1].

example.

Lets create a Dynamodb Table as below by CFN script with stream enabled.

```
DynamoDBTable:
Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
DeletionPolicy: Retain
Properties:
   AttributeDefinitions:
    -
      AttributeName: "id"
      AttributeType: "S"
   KeySchema:
    -
      AttributeName: "id"
      KeyType: "HASH"
   TableName: DynamoDBTable

   SSESpecification:
      SSEEnabled: true

   StreamSpecification:
      StreamViewType: "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
```

Then create a lambda execution role which has access to the stream as below,

```
DynamoDBStreamLambdaRole:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Statement:
    - Action:
      - sts:AssumeRole
      Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service:
        - lambda.amazonaws.com
    Version: '2012-10-17'
  Path: /
  RoleName:  "IAM-ROLE-DynamoDBStreamLambdaRole"
  Policies:
  - PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
      - Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeStream
        - dynamodb:GetRecords
        - dynamodb:GetShardIterator
        - dynamodb:ListStreams
        Effect: Allow
        Resource: !GetAtt DynamoDBTable.StreamArn

      Version: '2012-10-17'
    PolicyName: "IAM-POLICY-DynamoDBStreamLambdaStreamaccess"
  ManagedPolicyArns:
    - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
```

Then you can attach this role to the lambda as described in step 1.
[1]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-role

Comment: What makes you think OP uses Cloudformation?